# Postgres json to view

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table like this (with an jsonb column):
https://dbfiddle.uk/lGuHdHEJ

If I load this json with python into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data={

    "id": [1, 2],
    "myyear": [2016, 2017],
    "value": [5, 9]

}

data=json.dumps(data)

df=pd.read_json(data)

print (df)
```

I get this result:

```
   id  myyear  value
0   1    2016      5
1   2    2017      9
```

How can a get this result directly from the json column via sql in a postgres view?

Comment: Why do you want it in a `view` instead of a `table`?

Comment: The json will be updated from time to time and with a view I would be more flexible.  The python is just for an example and is should not be used for this

Comment: Why do you think the view would be more flexible? If you were to change the format of the JSON, you'd also have to change the view definition; you could just as well change the table instead.

Comment: Is there any good reason why your data is in parallel array format instead of the more customary array of objects format?

Comment: Hhmm ok thats true.  And how could I create a table from this json in sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: This assumes that your `id`, `my_year`, and `value` array are consistent and have the same length.**

This answer uses PostgresSQL's [`json_array_elements_text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) function to explode array elements to the rows.

```
select jsonb_array_elements_text(payload -> 'id')      as "id",
       jsonb_array_elements_text(payload -> 'bv_year') as "myyear",
       jsonb_array_elements_text(payload -> 'value')   as "value"
from main
```

And this gives the below output,

```
id  myyear value
1   2016    5
2   2017    9
```

Although this is not the best design to store the properties in `jsonb` object and could lead to data inconsistencies later. If it's in your control I would suggest storing the data where each property's mapping is clear. Some suggestions,

- You can instead have separate columns for each property.
- If you want to store it as jsonb only then consider `[{id: "", "year": "", "value": ""}]`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I receive the date in this format